# How to pass options to nomencl package in LyX?

Tags: lyx, nomencl

LyX automatically writes
`\usepackage{nomencl}`
to a .tex document if a nomenclature is inserted via Insert → List/ToC → Nomenclature. Fine. Now I'd like to add a corresponding entry to my table of contents.

The LyX user guide advises to add the `intoc` option to the "comma-separated document class
options list in the Document → Settings dialog". In the exported .tex file, however, only `\usepackage{nomencl}` would appear instead of `\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}`.

How do I effectively pass this option? The wiki (https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/Nomenclature) does not mention this either.

Comment: They're telling you to add `intoc` as a global option. Global options are passed to all packages. So that should work. Does it?

Comment: I'm following what they tell me, but it doesn't work - Nomenclature won't show in the TOC. Maybe there's a conflict between options `\documentclass[fleqn,english,refpage,intoc,greek,ngerman,BCOR=10mm,DIV=13,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Document >Settings… >Local layout.

Add
`PackageOptions nomencl intoc`

Press Validate. Apply.

View >Code Preview Pane and you'll see

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{intoc}{nomencl}
\usepackage{nomencl}
```